# c# Displaying List<Entity> into a list box

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to pull a solution from a system, and then display information about that solution in a listbox.

```
public static class SolutionActions
{
    public static List<Entity> getAllSolutions(IOrganizationService _serviceProxy)
    {
        QueryExpression querySampleSolution = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "solution",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "publisherid", "installedon", "version", "versionnumber", "friendlyname", "uniquename" }),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression(),
            NoLock = true,           
        };

        EntityCollection foundSolutions = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(querySampleSolution);
        return foundSolutions.Entities.ToList();
    }
}
```

and

```
if (sourceConnection != null)
{
    List<Entity> foundSolutions = SolutionActions.getAllSolutions(sourceConnection._orgService);
    //listSolutions.Items.AddRange(foundSolutions.ToArray());
    listSolutions.DataSource = foundSolutions;
}
```

I was just wondering if any of you had tips for how I could get the listbox to display PublishID, Installedon and such.

Comment: If you want to display various pieces of data from the object, you might look into other controls that provide columns, rather than a simple ListBox. Also, what UI are you using? WinForms? WPF? ASP? Tag the question accordingly.

Comment: what is the interface `IOrganizationService` ?? what does it look like?

Comment: and what does `Entity` class look like ? There is a lot lack of info here

Comment: Listbox only shows one string the one coming from the `ToString()` call and that would probably return, `System.Object.Entity` etc, if you want you can override the `ToString()` method if you have access to it, or ust another control to display all the fields.

Comment: To show a `List<Entity>`in `ListBox` you can use either of the following options: **1)** You can set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` of your `ListBox` to the property names of your `Entity`. `DisplayMember` property will be used to provide display text. **2)** You can handle `Format` event of `ListBox` and provide display text for each item. **3)** You can override `ToString` method of your `Entity` class and provide display text for the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to display. If for example each Entity has a Name property, and you want to display a list of the names, you could do this:

```
//using System.Linq;

listbox.Items.AddRange
(
    foundSolutions.Select( s => s.Name ).ToArray()
);
```